# Can you produce a force at a constant rate, but of a variable value?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

Sorry for the strange title, it's quite hard to describe. What I'm looking for is some sort of spring/mechanism that produces a force, of which is produced at a constant rate (**regardless of the extension**), however I also want to be able to adjust the output force manually.

The best analogy to describe what I'm looking for is a constant force spring, but one that has a force output that can be either increased or decreased at will. A constant force spring will produce the (near) same force, at any extension. I want this, however I also want to be able to vary the force value (again, regardless of the extension). Is there anything that can do what I've tried to describe above?

Comment: Are you thinking about something like this?  [An Adjustable Constant-Force Mechanism for Adaptive End-Effector Operations](https://asmedigitalcollection.asme.org/mechanicaldesign/article-abstract/134/3/031005/475509/An-Adjustable-Constant-Force-Mechanism-for?redirectedFrom=fulltext)

Comment: @AlfredCentauri Something like that, yeah. I was hoping that there'd be a straightforward and well known mechanism that could do what the journal pertains to.